# How to interpret this discussion of Verilog relational operators

Tags: verilog

This [discussion of Verilog relational operators at ASIC World](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators1.html) clearly has at least one mistake:

> - The result is a scalar value (example a < b)
> - 0 if the relation is false (a is bigger then b)
> - 1 if the relation is true (a is smaller then b)
> - x if any of the operands has unknown x bits (if a or b contains X)
>
> Note: If any operand is x or z, then the result of that test is
>   treated as false (0)

Clearly, "a is bigger than b" should be "a is bigger *than or equal to* b".

There is something else that looks wrong to me, but I don't know if it's just because I'm a Verilog novice. The last bullet point seems to contradict the subsequent note, unless there is a difference between an operand having all unknown bits (in which case the result of a relational operator will be x) and an operand being x (in which case the result will be 0).

Is there a difference between an operand being x and all of its bits being X? I know Verilog is case-sensitive.

Comment: Did you mean to say that " 'a is bigger than b' should be 'a is bigger *or equal to* b' "?

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, thank you. I'll fix in the question. An example of the mistaken correction! I should have watched out when I used "clearly". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verilog is known for its x-propagation pessimism.

From lrm 11.4.4

> An expression using these relational operators shall yield the scalar value 0 if the specified relation is false
>   or the value 1 if it is true. If either operand of a relational operator contains an unknown (x) or highimpedance
>   (z) value, then the result shall be a 1-bit unknown value (x).

so, if any of the values contains 'x' bits the result will be 'x'.

Now in case, when the result is used as a conditional expression, the `if` statement will take true brunch if and only if the result is '1'. Otherwise it will take the false branch. Also, there are conversion rules in verilog, where `x` and `z` values are converted to `0` in binary operations, which conditional operation is.

so, the comment on the site is correct, it is talking of the results of a test (as in if statement)

> If any operand is x or z, then the result of that **test** is treated as false (0)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take your comments to the author of that website.

I take the statement inside the ()'s to be an example

> 1 if the relation is true (if for example, a is smaller then b)

The subsequent note refers to a more general issue not specific to relational operators. When you have

```
if (expression) true_statement; else false_statement;
```

When *expression* evaluates to an X or 0, the false_statement branch is taken.

Also, Verilog is not case sensitive about numeric literals. `'habcxz` and `'hABCXZ` are equivalent.

Comment: Aha to the second part of your answer.